# Require environment variables to be given to image when run using `-e`

Tags: docker, environment-variables, dockerfile

I have a container image that requires an environment variable to be set in order to run. But if run with `-d`, unless the container is monitored, the person running the container won't notice something is missing. Is there a way that `docker [container] run` checks that an environment variable is given to the container before starting it.

Comment: If you have dockerfile read this: https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#substitute-environment-variables-in-compose-files

Answer (score 4):

In detach mode it not possible to print message that env is required, in your word when running with `-d`, but you can try a workaround:

Dockerfile

```
FROM alpine
COPY entrypoint.sh /usr/bin/
RUN chmod +x /usr/bin/entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["entrypoint.sh"]
```

entrypoint.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "starting container $hostname"
if [ -z "$REQUIRED_ENV" ]; then
  echo "Container failed to start, pls pass -e REQUIRED_ENV=sometest"
  exit 1
fi
echo "starting container with $REQUIRED_ENV"
#your long-running command from CMD
exec "$@"
```

So when you run with

```
docker run -it --name envtest  --rm env-test-image
```

it will exit with the message

```
starting container 
Container failed to start, pls pass -e REQUIRED_ENV=sometest
```

The workaround with detach mode

```
docker run -it --name envtest  -d --rm env-test-image && docker logs envtest
```

Answer (score 3):

*No: there is currently no way to make Docker aware of "dependencies" in the form of environment variables. This answer is for those who actually came here just looking for a canonical way to exit an entrypoint script in case of missing values.*

---

A POSIX shell takes the option **-u** (error when expanding unset variables) and **-e** (exit the shell when any statement returns an error/non-zero exit code). We also have **:** to evaluate-but-not-*invoke* an expression. Putting these together, we should be able to make an `entrypoint.sh` that works irrespective of sh-implementation like this:

```sh
#!/bin/sh -e -u

( : $USERNAME )
( : $PASSWORD ) 

exec "$@"
```

which will exit the script with an error akin to `PASSWORD: parameter not set`.

Another way of doing the same thing, but in context of the original example with a custom error message, could make use of the "*Display Error if Null or Unset*" operator (`${parm:?error}`) and look something like so:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
echo "starting container $hostname"
( : ${REQUIRED_ENV?"pls pass -e REQUIRED_ENV=sometest"} ) || exit 1
echo "starting container with $REQUIRED_ENV"
#your long-running command from CMD
exec "$@"
```